# hr color isn't clear

Tags: html, css

I set the color of `hr` to white and it became unclear and blurry,
and it looks like someone changed the opacity to 70%, like this:

[image]

How can I make it look as it should?

```css
hr {
    border: 10px dotted white;
    border-style: none none dotted;
    background-color: #ed8d8d;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

-------So, this is what I can see from the 'inspection' page when I click HR-----

```
element.style {
}
hr:not([size]) {
    height: 1px;
}
hr {
    border: 8px dotted white;
    border-style: none none dotted;
    background-color: #ed8d8d;
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}
hr {
    margin: 1rem 0;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: currentColor;
    border: 0;
    opacity: .25;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
hr {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: isolate;
    margin-block-start: 0.5em;
    margin-block-end: 0.5em;
    margin-inline-start: auto;
    margin-inline-end: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: var(--bs-font-sans-serif);
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
:root {
    --bs-blue: #0d6efd;
    --bs-indigo: #6610f2;
    --bs-purple: #6f42c1;
    --bs-pink: #d63384;
    --bs-red: #dc3545;
    --bs-orange: #fd7e14;
    --bs-yellow: #ffc107;
    --bs-green: #198754;
    --bs-teal: #20c997;
    --bs-cyan: #0dcaf0;
    --bs-white: #fff;
    --bs-gray: #6c757d;
    --bs-gray-dark: #343a40;
    --bs-primary: #0d6efd;
    --bs-secondary: #6c757d;
    --bs-success: #198754;
    --bs-info: #0dcaf0;
    --bs-warning: #ffc107;
    --bs-danger: #dc3545;
    --bs-light: #f8f9fa;
    --bs-dark: #212529;
    --bs-font-sans-serif: system-ui,-apple-system,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans","Liberation Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    --bs-font-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
    --bs-gradient: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Am3.png) how you want it to look?

Comment: No, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/r6hwuav4/ :) @Sops Can you share your current version and the expected one? It should be related to some other css.

Comment: @Christian Sorry, I don't usually jsfiddle.  I'll start now.

Comment: You don't need to "jsfiddle"; Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) should be enough to provide a [mre].

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown to indicate the opacity is anything other than the default. Please add the code that makes you think "someone changed the opacity to 70%".

Comment: I just added a picture!

Comment: @Sops Is there any other code you could share?  The CSS you have provided seems to work just fine.

Comment: In the page where you can see the problem, right click the hr element and choose "Inspect Element". That should show you all of the CSS rules that apply to it. My guess is that there's either a different CSS rule for `hr` elsewhere  that's changing its appearance or there's a rule in a parent element cascading down to it. Either way, inspecting should show enough CSS to reproduce the issue so you can add it to your snippet.

Comment: So, I just added the 'inspection' part of HR, would you please check again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added opacity in your css

```
hr {
margin: 1rem 0;
color: inherit;
background-color: currentColor;
border: 0;
opacity: .25;  //remove this
```

}

Comment: I could only see the "opacity" when I click the "inspect" on the web page, but actually adding 'opacity: 100%' to hr worked!

Answer (score 1):

By "blurry", I'm going to assume you mean this:

[image]

Just stick in an `opacity: 100%` line at the end to sharpen things up, or to what you want:

[image]

And the code:

```
hr {
    border: 10px dotted white;
    border-style: none none dotted;
    background-color: #ed8d8d;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 100%
}
```

Comment: I can’t see that adding opacity to this CSS as it stands makes any difference. There must be something else that is causing ‘blur’.

Comment: This post specifies the assumption on what "blur" means, and in a plausibe way. The proposed solution removes the prominent transparency as applied by OPs code, which in turn fixes what is explicitly assumed to be the stated "blur". @AHaworth Please elaborate what you understand to be the blur which OP complains about. The approach to fix the unintended transparency seems to have been confirmed by OP already, seeing the "accept" on the answer which takes that approach and solves/explains in a from a different angle but does not demonstrate the solutions effect as convincingly as this post.